# jQuery Validation - NotEqual Validation for same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have several dropdowns (with class name as month_dropdown) and the number of dropdowns are not constant. How can I achieve a NotEqual validation for them. I am using the jQuery Validation plugin.

This is what I have written -

`jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value != $(param).val();
}, "Please specify a different value");`

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("month_dropdown",{
    notEqual: ".month_dropdown"
});
```

However this is not perfectly working, even if I select a different month it pop me the message "Please specify a different value".

Comment: You may want to add a fiddle example with all the HTML/JS Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over each of the input elements and then check its value like.

In your case you are always checking the value of the first select element against itself because `$(param).val()` will always return the value of the first input element matching the selector `param`, so when the test is run against first input then its value will match against itself

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
  return this.optional(element) || $(param).not(element).get().every(function(item) {
    return $(item).val() != value;
  });
}, "Please specify a different value");

jQuery.validator.addClassRules("month_dropdown", {
  notEqual: ".month_dropdown"
});

jQuery(function($) {
  var validator = $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {},
    messages: {}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <select class="month_dropdown" name="el[1]">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <select class="month_dropdown" name="el[2]">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <select class="month_dropdown" name="el[3]">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot Arun!

Comment: This is the best solution out there. Fix for forms that also have repeaters inside and you need to validate entries that should be unique.